# how to prevent data overloading at different sessions using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web, overloading

I wrote some code for search page as follows

I declared variables in above page load as follows

```
static String strsql = "";
```

in page load

```
if(!isPostback)
{
   if(session["username"] != null)
   {
      loadprofiles(); // calling loadprofiles method
      bindlist();//loading gridview data
   }
}
```

now loadprofiles method wrote as follows

```
protected void loadprofiles()
{

   strsql = "select * from admintable where userid = '"+session["username"].Tostring()+"'";

}
```

now bindlist method is as follows

```
private void bindlist()
{
   SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(strsql, connection);
   //and some code for binding data to gridview
}
```

the problem is while two different users are login into this page from two different computers the user getting the data from second login persions

please help me to solve this problem...

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reasonable reason to declare `strsql ` as `static`?

Comment: no reason ...if i put private i am getting CommandText property has not been initialized error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare `strsql` as `static` since it will store value for **all** users - user1 will have access to the user2 `strsql` value. You have to remember that `static` is a member of a type, not an instance - it will be accessible for all users until `AppDomain` is unloaded.

In my opinion you shouldn't store SQL query in a variable(it seems unnecessary since session is accessible everywhere in your code).

I'd change your code to the

```
private void bindlist()
{
  SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand("select * from admintable where userid = '"+session["username"].Tostring()+"'", connection);
//and some code for binding data to gridview
}
```

EDIT:

Since you want to reuse query, you can return it from `loadprofiles()` method like follows:

```
protected string loadprofiles()
{
     strsql = "select * from admintable where userid = '"+session["username"].Tostring()+"'";
     // Do your logic there...
     return strsql;
}
```

and use it:

```
if(!isPostback)
{
   if(session["username"] != null)
   {
      var strsql = loadprofiles(); // calling loadprofiles method
      bindlist(strsql);//loading gridview data
   }
}
```

I believe you get the point.

Comment: please suggest another solutions instead of writing query because the query changes according to the user

Comment: @user3916850 - what changes exactly?

Comment: it has another option for bindlist method that means i have search property if some user searches profiles using search option that query also stores in strsql string...

Answer (score 0):

I was having `Session` issue for multiple tabs in a single browser.
In Default.aspx/Index.aspx write below code to generate a `Unique` session Id's.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack == false)   //If page loads for the first time
{
ViewState["_PageID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

To store any variable in session Use the following lines:

```
Session[ViewState["_PageID"].ToString() + "username"] = "testuserName";
```

To access anything stored based on the Session Id:

```
string userNameInSession = Session[ViewState["_PageID"].ToString() + "username"] as string;
```